# google-cloud-platform Google IoT MQTT client , subscribing to an external MQTT broker

Tags: client, mqtt, iot, publish-subscribe, broker

I have an external MQTT broker and I would like Google IoT cloud platform to subscribe to the broker.
Most of  Google IoT examples are written around the Google IoT platform broker, but my broker is external on another platform.

What Google  Iot code, methods can you suggest.

I can already verify with MQTT FX program the external broker is working.

Comment: Edit the question to include a diagram of the dataflow you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

If you want to send data to the Google IoT platform that is already being published to your broker, then you need to set up a bridge from that broker to the Google IoT platform.

This will need to have the bridge authenticate to the Google IoT platform.

How you set up the bridge will be specific to the type of broker you are already using. E.g. instructions for setting up a bridge with mosquitto are [here](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm45770162182128)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the high level  steps or concept as the Google IoT platform  samples are mostly written around the Googe  IoT broker.

Comment: No, because it will totally depend on what broker you are using

Comment: It's  quite simple in python on a PC,  to subscribe to a cloud MQTT broker...  import paho.mqtt.client as paho   and  mqttc = paho.Client() # Initialise a client object
mqttc.on_message = on_message       so I how do I do that in Google IoT?

Comment: As I already said, You don't! How you set up bridging is specific what ever type of broker you have running in the "clould"

Comment: If I can simply use a python program on my PC to subscribe  a MQTT broker then I should be able to do same in Google  IoT . It shouldn't need  a bridge.     I think all I need to do is change the Google MQTT client_ID  to the external cloud one in the google phython cloud

Comment: You CAN NOT edit anything on the Google IoT servers. Now if you want to use the same python you use to talk to you broker to talk to Google IoT's broker, that is not the question you asked.